# Why is rust expecting () when it should bool?

Tags: rust

My  rust code should return a boolean value, but for some reason, () is expected.
What's the matter here?

```
fn create_file(path: &Path) -> bool {
    // if file already exist
    if path.is_file(){
        false
    }
    let mut file = File::create(path);
    true
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
--> src/main.rs:53:9
    |
 52 | /     if path.is_file(){
 53 | |         false
    | |         ^^^^^ expected `()`, found `bool`
 54 | |     }
    | |     -- help: consider using a semicolon here
    | |_____|
    |       expected this to be `()`
```

but if you add ";" after false, then everything still works.

Comment: `return val` returns from a function. `val` in the end of a block makes this block return `val`. So you try to return `false` from `if path.is_file(){false}` block, not the entire function

Comment: To return in the middle of a function, only `return` syntax is applicable

Comment: and with any return type this happens

Comment: `return false;` is a way to go

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `return` or the `else`. Using `else` will make the if/else block to be the return expression

```rust
fn create_file(path: &Path) -> bool {
    // if file already exist
    if path.is_file(){
        false
    } else {
        let mut file = File::create(path);
        true
    }
}
```